# Difference usage between Formsauthentication.SetAuthCookie and Session

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication, session-state

I can't seem to find an answer to this seemingly simple question.

What is the difference between using the first or the later? Why would I use the first?

On MSDNAA I find the following regarding Formsauthentication.setCookie():

> Creates an authentication ticket for the supplied user name and adds
>   it to the cookies collection of the response, or to the URL if you
>   are using cookieless authentication.

Regarding Session:

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates the different ASP.NET pages that make up a
>   Web application. HTTP is a stateless protocol, meaning that your Web
>   server treats each HTTP request for a page as an independent request;
>   by default, the server retains no knowledge of variable values used
>   during previous requests. As a result, building Web applications that
>   need to maintain some cross-request state information (applications
>   that implement shopping carts, data scrolling, and so on) can be a
>   challenge. ASP.NET session state identifies requests received from the
>   same browser during a limited period of time as a session, and
>   provides the ability to persist variable values for the duration of
>   that session.

I'm especially interested in why I'd use formsauthentication.SetAuthCookie when I use a session cookie to check if the user is correctly logged in. E.g.:

```
if(Session["LoggedIn"] != null) {
    ...Do something here that only logged in users are allowed to do...
}
```

Comment: Is there really no one that can help me with this? At least with giving some material to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've found my answer on the asp.net site:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1587046.aspx/1#4012585